# Finding the location of a town in Russia - where to post

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

About 20 years ago I travelled to Russia and stayed in a community about 50 miles outside of Moscow.  I can remember phonetically how to pronounce the place but I cannot find it geographically, and would very much like to.

I was hoping there would be a suitable Stack community to post this question to, but aside perhaps from "travel" I'm at a loss.

It's not tricky to phrase the question in such a way that it does conform to the Q&A format rather than "I'm looking for this place I went once that sounds like ...", so I have no concerns here - I wonder however if there is any Stack community for the actual question.  would Travel be acceptable for this?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to ask on Travel.SE's meta as that was my first thought as well, but since you don't have 5 rep there required to post, that won't work.

Comment: If you already think it might fit on travel.SE, why don't you ask there (either straight on the main site, or [on their meta](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/) or in [their chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here))?

Comment: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/questions-such-as-where-can-i-find-one-thing-too-localized

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have an ["identify-this" tag on Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this). It's used for "where is this cool building in this photograph" and "help me find the name of the hotel I stayed at" kind of questions, along with "what is this weird thing I saw while travelling, does anyone know what it is for?". Take a look and see if you feel ok asking your "what was this city?" question there. I think it would be ok.

Comment: That tag looks just the ticket, thanks.  I'll do this.

Comment: Just for future reference - I followed this advice and got a reply almost instantly.  http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47896/identifying-a-community-in-russia